# Why does ReactJS not catch rendering exceptions of child components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the written the following function to render an error page when the top level container I wish to render encounters an error:

```
function unsafeRender(callback) {
  try {
    var renderedComponent = callback();
    return renderedComponent;
  } catch(err) {
    return (<ErrorPage error={err} />);
  }
}
```

The top level container has this method called in its `render()` method:

```
render: function() {
  return unsafeRender(function() {
    return <Component />;
  });
}
```

When the render method of the `<Component />` throws an error, it does not get caught by the unsafeRender function. Only when I apply it to the component directly does the method get called. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxmantz/69z2wepo/40277/) for the source code.

Why is this the case and do I really have to apply such a method to every child component in order for it to work instead of being able to use it once in a top level container?

Comment: See [Error boundaries: Recover from errors thrown in `render` #2461](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2461).

Comment: Explains a lot. Thank you @FelixKling!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by a known issue in React. See Felix Kling's comment under my question for the link to the issue on Github.